# Before 1.13.x I am use Ember.View.extend() to add custom css class. What I must use now?

Tags: ember.js

I have page design, which needs to be displayed into `div` element with class `displayInline`:

```
displayInline: { display: inline-block; }
```

(there are some makeup designers with hands derived from ...).

Before `Ember.js` 1.13.x I use hint from `Ember.js` documentation:

```
app.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    classNames: ['displayInline']
});
```

Which correctly produces what I want:

```
<div id="ember493" class="ember-view displayInline">...</div>
```

This worked for me now, but generates `deprecation` and may not work in next `Ember.js` releases:

> DEPRECATION: Ember.View is deprecated. Consult the Deprecations Guide for a migration strategy. See http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-view for more details.

How to add custom `css` class for Application?

I tried searching in Docs and Web, but found no results.

Comment: Why not simply set the class in the `application.hbs` template?

Comment: It's not worked, this html markup needs this class at top level `div`, in `application.hbs` classes set only on nested `div`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am found two ways and it's worked in Ember version > 1.13

1. Use solution from [Issue#11906](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11906), e.g. change:

```js
app.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    classNames: ['displayInline']
});
```

to:

```js
app.ApplicationView = Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['displayInline']
});
```

2. Make right `css` selector:

```css
body > div.ember-view {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PedroCheckos' answer will work if you're willing to add another element to the DOM. But if you don't want to do that (which I didn't), then that solution doesn't really work well. Unfortunately, the Ember team hasn't provided a solution for this yet. If you look at the [view deprecation guide](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-view), it suggests workarounds that don't really apply. Until routable components land (likely in 2.1 or 2.2), you're stuck with extending the view as you're doing now.

However, the Ember team *has* [provided an addon](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-legacy-views) that will eliminate the deprecation notice. I suggest using that addon until routable components land, then swapping out your view/controller for a component.